# How to insert all the values from a spinner to SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-spinner

How to insert the values of spinner to SQL lite database in android?

for instance my code has

```
ArrayList<String> yr = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 2015; i <= 2030; i++) {
        yr.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yr);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     year.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

and i want to save the year selected by the user on the database

Comment: you can insert items in your database when you are adding it into your arraylist yr.

Comment: Did it answer your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Implement `OnItemSelectedListener` for your class then call `setOnItemSelectedListener` for the spinner.

```
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Then add the following which gets invoked after year is selected in the dropdown:

```
@Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
      //insert item to db
   }
```

Comment: I think you didn't get question properly. he want to add all spinner values in database and he doesn't specified that he want to add only selected item in his database. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani Yes sir you are wrong. See the line below the code "and i want to save the year selected by the user on the database"

Comment: ohh sorry but i think here mistake is not done by us but there is a conflict in question. In title of question he wrote all the values of spinner and in question he said selected value.

Answer (score -1):

May be this will work

```
public void insertValuesInDb(ArrayAdapter adapter) { 
  for(int i = 0; i < adapter.size(); i++) { 
        item = adapter.getItem(i)
        //insert item in database
  } 
}
```

If it helps you then don't forget to mark answer as accepted and if you have any further queries you can ask them in comments!